# window.requestFileSystem on Phonegap for Android fails with code 9

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm using Phonegap to develop an HTML5 application for android but when I try the following code to acquire a file system:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsSuccess, fsFail);
```

I get error `code 9` i.e. `INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR`.

According to [this source](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/18832), this is caused by the lack of an SD card on the device, but my android device has 1.5GB of internal storage on it. and of course not all devices are expected to have external SD on them!

How can I alternate this behaviour and tell phoneGap to use any file system on the device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also, as you said if your device doesn't have an SD Card it will fail. What device is it?

Get back to me on this and if you are really stuck I will raise a bug on PhoneGap and see if I can get it fixed before the 1.4 release drops Jan 30th.

Comment: I already have that permission. DEVICE: Dell Streak. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Okay I've created a bug to describe your problem (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-172) and I'll see if I can get the fix into 1.4.

Comment: I can test this properly on my phone as it will not unmount my SD card. Can you email me at simon [dot] macdonald [at] gmail [dot] com and I can send you a jar/js for you to try.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald I'm getting error code:5, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

What do you do in your function `fsSuccess`? I'm aware of that error since I tried to open a file with `exclusive=true` although it already existed.

And why requesting 0 bytes of space? Try to set an value greater then 0 like `1024*1024` (1MB). Possibly that's the problem...